# Differentiate $ z=\frac{A}{y^8} + Be^y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate $$\displaystyle z=\frac{A}{y^8} + Be^y$$
This $A$ and $B$ stuff is throwing me off. Are they just variables?

Comment: Diff with respect to what?

Comment: A and B will be given in your book just scroll your eye balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are probably meant to be constants in this equation. So again, I'll assume you want differentiate $z$ with respect $y$: $$z=\frac{A}{y^8} + B e^y \implies \frac{dz}{dy}= A \cdot \frac{d(1/y^8)}{dy} + B \cdot \frac{d(e^y)}{dy} = A \cdot \left( -\frac{8}{y^9} \right) + Be^y$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need $$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}$$

Hints; Remember the following;

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(cy)}{\mathrm{d}x}=c\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ for c a function independent of $x$.

And

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x^n}{\mathrm{d}x}=n x^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$ \frac {dz}{dy} = \frac {-8A}{y^9} + Be^y $

Answer (score 0):

I think A and B are constants. Thus,

z= A/y8 +  Be^y

Differentiate with respect to y,

dz/dy= dAy^-8/dy + dBe^y/dy

dz/dy= -8Ay^-9 + Be^y

Ans.